# Como gerar arquivos JSON através de formulários?

Tags: php, json, input

Quero armazenar os dados que os usuários colocam nos inputs em arquivos JSON separados para poder utilizar depois.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou pesquisar por `php` e `json` aqui no site? Veja isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+json. Com certeza uma das perguntas irá te ajudar no que precisa; pelo menos indicando o que você deve estudar.

Comment: Você vai precisar utilizar o arquivo no client ou no backend?

Comment: eu preciso mostrá-los ao usuário depois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tiver pegando os dados via formulário, você pode usar o *json_encode()* antes de salvar os dados no arquivo. Exemplo:

**form.html**

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="save.php">
   <input type="text" name="nome">
   <input type="text" name="sobrenome">
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

**save.php (arquivo que recebe a requisição do formulário)**

```
<?php

// Pega a requisição post e transforma em JSON.
$values = json_encode($_POST);

// Armazena no final do arquivo os valores recebidos.
file_put_contents('nome_e_path_do_arquivo.ext', $values, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Poderia me explicar mais detalhadamente essa segunda parte do save.php?

Comment: Qual parte? O encode ou o file_put_contents!

Comment: os dois, se você tiver paciência e disposição, por favor.

Comment: Você me ajudaria se eu te explicasse melhor como é o projeto e o que eu estou tentando fazer?

Comment: Seria bom sempre explicar o máximo possível do seu problema e dúvida. Isso nos ajuda a fornecer melhores respostas. Mas tentando explicar um pouco do que você pediu:

**json_encode** é o método que irá transformar todo o array $_POST em uma string json (como você quer);
**file_put_contents** é o método que tenta escrever algum em um arquivo, se o arquivo não existir, ele cria se tiver permissão na pasta para isso. O $values é o valor que será adicionado ao arquivo e o FILE_APPEND diz para adicionar a linha no final do arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso com o `javascript`:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify($("#id_do_meu_form").serializeArray());
```

O conteúdo ficará na variável `myJSON`, é só utiliza-lo da forma que preferir.

Comment: Não será possível armazenar em arquivo utilizando JavaScript e os dados seriam perdidos de uma sessão para outra. Se quiser manter a resposta, acredito que você poderia torná-la completa dando uma solução para persistir os dados.

Comment: então não tem como criar uma arquivo json separado com esses dados?